# In scripts, is it better to cd working directory or prefix paths

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I have a script that is supposed to perform work in specified directory, is it better to prefix all paths with this directory, or save this hassle and just `cd` to the working directory. For example

```bash
WORK_DIR="$1"

process data >"$WORK_DIR/result.txt"
grep "Error" "$WORK_DIR/result.txt"
```

or

```bash
WORK_DIR="$1"

cd "$WORK_DIR"
process data >result.txt
grep "Error" result.txt
```

I understand there would be difference if I run this script with `source`, but is there a preferred/convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way is to use the prefix, and I could think of few reasons:

1. It's easier read and maintain. It's easier to grep for `$WORK_DIR` in the script, rather than searching for the last `cd` before this, especially if the script is long and you perform `cd` multiple times inside the script.
2. In your specific example, if anyone decides to edit the script and add few lines between the "process" and the "grep", he might `cd` to a different directory, in which case the `grep` line will fail. If you use the prefix, it doesn't matter what happens in the middle.
3. If during the run of the script someone deletes and recreates `$WORK_DIR`, your script will be inside a deleted directory. If you use the prefix, even if the directory is deleted and recreated, you'll write to the new directory.

Comment: That third item is actually a strong argument for `cd`, as that ensures you don't look for `result.txt` in a different directory to where you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

The second form is dangerous if you run the script without `-e` flag set.
If the `cd` fails for any reason, then execution will continue with the next line, *even though the working directory is unchanged*.  That's not what you want, and might even be a security vulnerability.

Comment: That's easily fixed with `cd "$WORK_DIR" || exit`. I would avoid using `set -e` unless it's a trivial script.

Comment: Yes, that's the other alternative.  I was going to mention that, but it didn't really fit the flow of narrative.  Conversely, I rarely _unset_ `-e` for a section of script; I guess it always depends on your experience.  Either way, the sample presented needs more attention paid to the failure cases, which is what I wanted to highlight.